# Как посчитать продолженный угол (более 360 градусов) с помощью сенсора ориентации Android Studio

Tags: android

За основу взял код ниже. После поворота устройства на 410 градусов, например, хотелось бы получить не 50 градусов, а именно 400. После 359 снова 0 градусов идет. Как можно реализовать такую идею?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

//Объявляем картинку для компаса
private ImageView HeaderImage;
//Объявляем функцию поворота картинки
private float RotateDegree = 0f;
//Объявляем работу с сенсором устройства
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
//Объявляем объект TextView
TextView CompOrient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Связываем объект ImageView с нашим изображением:
    HeaderImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.CompassView);

    //TextView в котором будет отображаться градус поворота:
    CompOrient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Header);

    //Инициализируем возможность работать с сенсором устройства:
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Устанавливаем слушателя ориентации сенсора
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //Останавливаем при надобности слушателя ориентации
    //сенсора с целью сбережения заряда батареи:
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    //Получаем градус поворота от оси, которая направлена на север, север = 0 градусов:
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
    CompOrient.setText("Отклонение от севера: " + Float.toString(degree) + " градусов");

    //Создаем анимацию вращения:
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
            RotateDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    //Продолжительность анимации в миллисекундах:
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(0);

    //Настраиваем анимацию после завершения подсчетных действий датчика:
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    //Запускаем анимацию:
    HeaderImage.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    RotateDegree = -degree;

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    //Этот метод не используется, но без него программа будет ругаться
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION
>
> This constant was deprecated in API level 8. use
>   SensorManager.getOrientation() instead.

Для того чтоб получить желаемый результат можно использовать. `Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE`

Вот пример кода, который будет подсчитывать абсолютную величину с момента старта.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private float rotateY = 0f;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float degree = Math.round(event.values[1]);
    rotateY += degree;
    Log.d("TAG", "rotateY: " + rotateY);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
}
```

Ось можете сменить: X,Y,Z
event.values[0] event.values[1] 
event.values[2], ну или все использовать, вам решать.

Comment: Оказалось проще, чем я представлял и пытался сделать) Все работает, спасибо